# How to read polar coordinates of radiation pattern

Tags: rf, antenna, pcb-antenna, propagation

I have a PCB antenna which datasheet provides the following radiation pattern graphs:

[image]

There seems to be a "weak" direction which the antenna signals is going to be very weak.

Which direction is the "weakest" in signal propagation for this antenna, especially corresponding to the 270 degrees coordinate of the XZ graph? Is it -X or -Z direction?

Comment: If you can update your post and add a link to the antenna data-sheet it will be helpful. Usually (but not always) data-sheets have drawings that explain the orientation of the antenna relative to the radiation pattern, or in other words, for the XZ cross-section, what is missing is the Y axis.

Comment: There is the picture of the board on the top left. If the board was on the XZ pattern elsewhere in the datasheet, I would not have asked the question.

Comment: If there is a standard, not everyone follows it. I found 2 different specifications that specifically showed where the zero degree reference is, unfortunately, they are both different. Your best bet is to ask the vendor. Or, post a link to the specification, maybe there is something that you missed..